# Jersey 2.0 (Jax-RS 2.0) Restfull Webservice With Maven Throwing Exception While Running on Glassfish 3.1.2?

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am getting this exception while running web service in net beans What exactly I am missing? I Tried to deploy web service using mvn and stuff command but still same exception. Newbie in Java. Help Appreciated highly.

Web.xml

```
     <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>async-app</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.examples.server.async.AsyncJaxrsApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>async-app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
- <parent>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.examples</groupId> 
  <artifactId>server-async-standalone</artifactId> 
  <version>2.0</version> 
  </parent>
  <artifactId>server-async-standalone-webapp</artifactId> 
  <packaging>war</packaging> 
  <name>jersey-examples-server-async-standalone-webapp</name> 
  <description>Standalone Jersey JAX-RS asynchronous server-side processing example web application.</description> 
- <dependencies>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId> 
  <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId> 
  <scope>provided</scope> 
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
- <profiles>
- <profile>
  <id>examples-source-zip</id> 
- <!--  do not create source zip bundles 
  --> 
- <build>
- <plugins>
- <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId> 
- <configuration>
  <skipAssembly>true</skipAssembly> 
  </configuration>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
  </profile>
  </profiles>
  </project>
```

Exception Message:-

```
[#|2014-02-19T15:01:10.928+0530|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=73;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]

[#|2014-02-19T15:01:10.928+0530|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=73;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app|#]

[#|2014-02-19T15:01:10.977+0530|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=73;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists|#]
```

Comment: I came across the same problem, and it looks like GF 3.1.x is not compatible with Jersey 2.x. This entry confirms it http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/jersey-2-x-on-glassfish-3-1-x-td7581312.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `com/google/common/collect/Lists` so I guess the deployed war misses a jar. What do you have in your pom.xml ?

Comment: I have edited the question and added pom file code please check. Thanks for consideration

Comment: Your `pom.xml` includes a dependency on `org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet` but with no specific version. Which one did your mvn build take ? Are you sure it is compatible with the version of Glassfish you want to deploy on ? Besides (I'm not a Glassfish expert), how did the `guava` library happened to be in your project ? is it a transitive dependency or ?

Comment: Seems rocket science to me, I have downloaded jersey-examples-2.0-all and was testing one of example which suits my need of async Restfull Webservice. I just imported that example into netbeans and tried to run. But Because I am newbie in java facing mentioned problems. What are the options I have?

Comment: It seems Glassfish version is 3.1.2 and maven 2.2.1. So is it ok or not? Do I need to upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I have upgraded everything like netbeans 7.2.1 to 7.4 jdk 1.7 jre7. glassfish 4.0 tomcat 7.0.41.0 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here is that **Glassfish 3** is not compatible with **Jersey 2**.

If you want to use Jersey 2, you have to use Glassfish 4.